# mongoDB - How do master-detail structure grouped detail collection specific fields summary

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb

In a mongodb database with a master-detail structure, how do I ensure that the data in the detail table is grouped according to the status area while querying the master table. For example ...

```
Master, Row, Job, Fields, [Detail Status Grouped Count / Summary Object]
```

**Edited:**

**sms_jobs collection example data is :**

```
// 1
{
    "_id": NumberInt("1"),
    "company": {
        "id": NumberInt("1"),
        "name": "",
        "sms_gateway_id": NumberInt("1"),
        "sms_gateway_parameters": {
            "password": "",
            "username": ""
        },
        "is_active": true
    },
    "source_type": "form",
    "source": {
        "id": NumberInt("2"),
        "company_id": NumberInt("1"),
        "title": "Import Data Demo",
        "description": "<p>Üst Açıklama</p>",
        "footer_description": "<p>Alt Açıklama</p>",
        "thanks_message": "Katiliminiz icin tesekkur ederiz.",
        "sms_message": "{company} KVKK Aydinlatma Metni ve Acik Riza Onayi icin Dogrulama Kodunuz : {code} ( {form_link} )",
        "digest": null,
        "ts_digest": null,
        "is_active": true,
        "is_locked": false
    },
    "description": "Import Data Demo",
    "status": "waiting",
    "job_count": NumberInt("22145"),
    "updated_at": ISODate("2020-08-15T17:00:49.252Z"),
    "created_at": ISODate("2020-08-15T16:59:10.899Z")
}
```

**sms_job_details collection example data is :**

```
// 1
{
    "_id": NumberInt("221462"),
    "sms_job_id": NumberInt("1"),
    "gsm": "",
    "schedule_at": ISODate("2020-08-15T19:41:44.827Z"),
    "raw_message": "{name} {surname} {id_number} {form_link} {reject_link}",
    "message": "",
    "status": "waiting", // I want this statuses grouped count my master table rows in line object
    "expire_at": "2020-08-18T17:40:44.967Z",
    "updated_at": ISODate("2020-08-15T18:45:53.727Z"),
    "created_at": ISODate("2020-08-15T18:45:53.727Z")
}

// 2
{
    "_id": NumberInt("221463"),
    "sms_job_id": NumberInt("1"),
    "gsm": "",
    "schedule_at": ISODate("2020-08-15T19:41:44.827Z"),
    "raw_message": "{name} {surname} {id_number} {form_link} {reject_link}",
    "message": "",
    "status": "failed", // I want this statuses grouped count my master table rows in line object
    "expire_at": "2020-08-18T17:40:44.967Z",
    "updated_at": ISODate("2020-08-15T18:45:53.727Z"),
    "created_at": ISODate("2020-08-15T18:45:53.727Z")
}

// 3
{
    "_id": NumberInt("221464"),
    "sms_job_id": NumberInt("1"),
    "gsm": "",
    "schedule_at": ISODate("2020-08-15T19:41:44.827Z"),
    "raw_message": "{name} {surname} {id_number} {form_link} {reject_link}",
    "message": "",
    "status": "success", // I want this statuses grouped count my master table rows in line object
    "expire_at": "2020-08-18T17:40:44.967Z",
    "updated_at": ISODate("2020-08-15T18:45:53.727Z"),
    "created_at": ISODate("2020-08-15T18:45:53.727Z")
}
```

I experimented for approximately 4-5 hours. I could get the closest result with the **following query**.

```
db.getCollection("sms_jobs").aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "sms_job_details",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "sms_job_id",
        as: "data"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$data"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            id: "$_id",
            status: "$data.status"
        },
        qty: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: "$_id.id",
        qty: 1,
        status: "$_id.status"
    }
}])
```

**And get this result :**

```
// 1
{
    "qty": 22145,
    "_id": NumberInt("4"),
    "status": "success"
}

// 2
{
    "qty": 1,
    "_id": NumberInt("3"),
    "status": "success"
}

// 3
{
    "qty": 22142,
    "_id": NumberInt("1"),
    "status": "success"
}

// 4
{
    "qty": 1,
    "_id": NumberInt("1"),
    "status": "failed"
}

// 5
{
    "qty": 2,
    "_id": NumberInt("1"),
    "status": "waiting"
}

// 6
{
    "qty": 1,
    "_id": NumberInt("3"),
    "status": "failed"
}

// 7
{
    "qty": 3,
    "_id": NumberInt("3"),
    "status": "waiting"
}
```

**What do I want ?**

The query result I want is as follows.

```
// 1
{
    "_id": NumberInt("1"),
    "company": {
        "id": NumberInt("1"),
        "name": "",
        "sms_gateway_id": NumberInt("1"),
        "sms_gateway_parameters": {
            "password": "",
            "username": ""
        },
        "is_active": true
    },
    "source_type": "form",
    "source": {
        "id": NumberInt("2"),
        "company_id": NumberInt("1"),
        "title": "Import Data Demo",
        "description": "<p>Üst Açıklama</p>",
        "footer_description": "<p>Alt Açıklama</p>",
        "thanks_message": "Katiliminiz icin tesekkur ederiz.",
        "sms_message": "{company} KVKK Aydinlatma Metni ve Acik Riza Onayi icin Dogrulama Kodunuz : {code} ( {form_link} )",
        "digest": null,
        "ts_digest": null,
        "is_active": true,
        "is_locked": false
    },
    "description": "Import Data Demo",
    "status": "waiting",
    "job_count": NumberInt("22145"),
    "updated_at": ISODate("2020-08-15T17:00:49.252Z"),
    "created_at": ISODate("2020-08-15T16:59:10.899Z"),
// Added part...
    "status_countes": {
        "success": NumberInt("20"),
        "failed": NumberInt("2"),
        "waiting": NumberInt("11"),
        "canceled": NumberInt("0"),
        "total": NumberInt("33")
    },
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help...

Comment: $group + $push.

Comment: I have tried a lot. if possible, could you give an example?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: You need to show us what code you have written to try to solve this problem, and what the results are,

Comment: I updated my question. I have added more detailed information on your request. Thank you.